# How to use package from com.sun

Tags: java, osgi

I'm working on a commercial software which needs the package `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`
I tried many times import the package but many times unsuccessful because I use OSGI and this makes the import of the package very difficult.

I found the original source code here:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.java.html

One quick way will be just copy the code and use it. But if I do this I may violate the license because my application source code is closed. Can you give me some advice how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get it: `CachedRowSetImpl` is a class, not a package; and as it contained in `rt.jar` you may just use it without any OSGI mumbojumbo?

Comment: What if I just place com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl into my java package alongside with my closed source? Is this a violation of the license?

Comment: I imagine copying Oracle's source without permission would violate the license, however if you copy the OpenJDK version which has a different license you should be ok.  You can allows OSGi to use com.sun packages by a configuration change. i.e. you have to tell it which package are exported from the JVM and you need to add it to the list.

Comment: OpenJDK is Gnu GPL licensed, which means that if you use the source code your application would have to be Gnu GPL as well, otherwise you infringe on their copyleft (sic). But if the class is in `rt.jar` as it's being said here, it should be available through java runtime, and it shouldn't be a problem using it.

Answer (score 0):

When you start an OSGi framework. It supplies all of the base, system packages, to the environment as part of the framework bundle.

There is a restriction on that. By default it doesn't supply any of the com.sun.* classes that comes with Java as they aren't considered part of the "java library"

To get these classes into the OSGi environment you just need to use a fragment bundle that will extend the framework bundle and expose the required classes.

I highly recommend reading this blog post by Felix Meschberger who walks through an example of this process

http://blog.meschberger.ch/2008/10/osgi-bundles-require-classes-from.html